Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: 'The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.' in c#
I am reading mails from Exchange server by using c# with below code i am getting an error like

Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException: 'The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.'

When i googled i got information like microsoft stopped direct authentication and now we have to use Open Authenticaion(Oauth).
I was going through the steps mentioned in the link OauthToken
There in the first step Registration process ,i logged in through my office id and in the search box, i searched App registrations where i am getting a Warning:

Your administrator has disabled the App registrations experience in the Azure portal. You can still register or manage applications using PowerShell or another client such as Visual Studio.

And i got stuck here?
So my question what would be the next step and is this a correct process?
Code used is as below
    ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2); // Use your Exchange version
                                                                                                            
        _service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("test@emind.com", "testpwd", "hoeng");
        _service.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"); // Use your EWS endpoint
        Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet propSet = new Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
        propSet.Add(ItemSchema.MimeContent);
        propSet.Add(ItemSchema.TextBody);
        FolderView view = new FolderView(100);
        FindFoldersResults findFolderResults = _service.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.Root, view);
        foreach (EmailMessage email in _service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(10)))
        {
            var message = EmailMessage.Bind(_service, email.Id, propSet);
        } 


Do you have admin privileges for the Exchange tenant in question?

@Dmitry Streblechenko i dont have ,thats what that error shows
Your administrator has disabled the App registrations experience in the Azure portal. You can still register or manage applications using PowerShell or another client such as Visual Studio.

PS won't help you. If you are not an admin, you cannot enable any apps. That is what the admins are for.

@Dmitry Streblechenko how to get admin privilege

You need to talk with whoever is managing Exchange for your org.

@Dmitry Streblechenko thanks i will check this and i can see this Entra implemented in 2022 onwards.Now my question is ,is it a one time work to get the ID, so that i can generate it with the help of exchange guy and store it or every time required?

One time. Once you have the id, you can prompt the user for the credentials through OAuth.
